# Any brew command errors with "Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead."

Tags: macos, homebrew

Almost all brew commands error with `Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.` . Here are some commands I ran with output:

```
$ brew services
  Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.
$ brew update
  Error: homebrew/homebrew-apache does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-apache` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-dupes does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-php does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-php` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-python does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-python` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-science does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-science` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-versions does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-versions` to remove it.
$ brew untap homebrew/homebrew-apache
  Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.
$ brew tap homebrew/cask
$ brew update
  Error: homebrew/homebrew-apache does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-apache` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-dupes does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-php does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-php` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-python does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-python` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-science does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-science` to remove it.
  homebrew/homebrew-versions does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-versions` to remove it.
$ brew untap homebrew/homebrew-apache
  Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.
$ brew config
  HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.1.2
  ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
  HEAD: bc9b98aa0ba777889218ac51f67ccc76b0be6a28
  Last commit: 2 days ago
  Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
  Core tap HEAD: 570facf3dbfb7b9cf8e8f73c2cb18d0c3bd8d758
  Core tap last commit: 52 minutes ago
  Core tap branch: master
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
  HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
  HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ZwGWHKEhwY/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
  HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4
  Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable- 
  ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
  CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
  Clang: 12.0 build 1200
  Git: 2.24.3 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
  Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
  macOS: 11.2.3-x86_64
  CLT: N/A
  Xcode: 12.3
  XQuartz: 2.7.9 => /opt/X11
```

Where does this reference to caskroom/cask come from and how can I fix it? Is there a way to remove caskroom/cask?

Comment: Is this in any way related to programming? If you think that there is any bug in Brew, please use their bugtracker to report it

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to understand where the reference to caskroom/cask comes from. I'm not sure if this is a bug in homebrew.